# Braintree - get payment status report

Tags: braintree

I need to know how I can get back the payment status report using Braintree API in any conditions after payment.

**Reasons:**
This case happened during transaction process the internet sometimes goes offline.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

The request docs show a good example on how to [find the status of a transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/find). In addition I would check out the [response docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction#status) for a list of all possible statuses.